# android development, implementing google maps

Tags: android, maps, keystore, keytool

straight from http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html it says:

To register for a Maps API Key, you need to provide an MD5 fingerprint of the certificate that you will use to sign your application. Before you visit the registration page, use Keytool to generate the fingerprint of the appropriate certificate.
First, determine which key you will use to sign your application at release and make sure of the path to the keystore that contains it.
Next, run Keytool with the -list option, against the target keystore and key alias. The table below lists the options you should use.

I dont understand the directions to do this.  I tried on the terminal using:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore microjobs.keystore -alias mjkey -keyalg RSA
```

and entered name, and city state then:

keytool -list

but it returns:

keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file exists, but is empty:

What should i do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Might be an [access](http://www.coderanch.com/t/134648/Security/keytool-error-java-io-filenotfoundexception) problem to the folder ?

Also, later in the page you reference in your question, if you look [here](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#getdebugfingerprint), Eclipse can help you generate and locate your API key.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the folder containing the keystore file, and then run

```
keytool -list -alias your_alias -keystore your_file_name
```

where your_file_name is just the file name, without path.